# Fixing content relative to parent

Tags: jquery, html, css, parallax

I'm building a website whereby when scrolling, it will appear as if the section below which has a height of 100vh, overlaps the current section like so:

https://i.gyazo.com/152c66a9476dd522958c77158f669c14.mp4

The problem I'm having at the moment is that the content itself can't be fixed to the relative parent since `position: fixed` is relative to the viewport and not the parent container.

So far, what I managed to achieve is:

**Creating a function that calculates where the content is on the page and 'achors' it to the top of the viewport if it's near (not really the affect I'm after, but using `position: absolute` here makes the content move up with the section when scrolling when I need to to be overlapped with the section being scrolled to)**

```
    function parallaxScroll() {
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        $(".section-text").each(function(){
            $(this).css('margin-top', $(window).scrollTop() - $(this).parent().position().top);
        });
    });
```

**The backgrounds have the overlapping effect achieved by setting the following CSS:**

```
background: url(/images/objectives/titanic.jpg) no-repeat fixed;
background-position: center center;
background-size: cover;
```

What I would like to achieve is very similar to the video in the link except I'd like the content itself to move with the sections (up and down) whilst being fixed to the section it belongs to and not stay in the viewport and hidden with the use of `z-index`.

I'm not 100% sure this is the best approach.

Any help is appreciated greatly.

Comment: So you want it to  - be fixed till it's parent catches it - and than to scroll-away together with the parent?

Comment: I'd like the content to be fixed to the parent container which can be achieved by making the content positioned relatively and then when scrolling, the section below will overlap the section in view with the content still in the same position inside its container. But at the same time the section below will overlap the current section. If that makes sense without a visual aid.

Comment: I still don't understand... so the content should never ever actually move?

Comment: The content shouldn't move, just the sections overlapping each over as you scroll. I understand with the way I've coded/styled this that all I've achieved is an illusion of that happening.

Comment: Ahh I think I understand - let me create an example and let's see if it fits

Comment: Very helpful - thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to:

- Scrollable page with sections
- Sections with fixed background attachment
- Content should be *"center-fixed"* at all time (fixed in the middle of it's respective container)
- While scrolling the page each *next section* should overlap the previous (content included!)

What I'd do is:

- Use CSS `position:fixed` content
- Wrap content into clipped `clip-path: polygon` elements (having heights equal as `section` parents)

## Fixed content

```css
section { 
  height: 100vh;
}

.fix {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50vh;
  left: 10vw;
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  max-width: 33vw;
  color: #fff;
}

.clip {
  height: inherit;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

/* Just some general styles... */
*{margin:0;box-sizing:border-box;}
html,body{height:100%;font:14px/1.4 sans-serif;}
h1{font-weight: 100;font-size:9vh} p{font-size: 2.8vh;}

[class^='bg-'],[class*=' bg-'] {background: fixed center/cover none no-repeat;}
.bg-1{background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1VOY.jpg');}
.bg-2{background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6u3t.jpg');}
.bg-3{background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3ZBA.jpg');}
```

```html
<section class="bg-1">
  <div class="clip">
    <div class="fix">
      <h1>staircase to</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique corporis saepe doloribus optio nulla laudantium accusantium esse nostrum soluta!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="bg-2">
  <div class="clip">
    <div class="fix">
      <h1>the subterrain of</h1>
      <p>Eveniet quaerat architecto nemo in eum accusamus ipsa! Nisi hic laboriosam nesciunt, magnam tempore, praesentium, eveniet iusto est inventore doloremque animi iure</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="bg-3">
  <div class="clip">
    <div class="fix">
      <h1>our great city</h1>
      <p>Optio nulla laudantium accusantium esse nostrum soluta! Consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique corporis saepe doloribus optio nulla</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**The trick**

by setting `position:fixed;` to the content elements - we end up seeing them overlapped on top of each-other. Bad. But...
if we wrap every one into a clipping parent - such will only appear by scrolling the clipping parent in-view.

---

## Sticky content

instead of fixing the content, here's a *sticky* version of the above

```css
section { 
  height: 100vh;
}

.fix {
  position: sticky;
  top: 20vh;
  padding-bottom: 20vh;
  left: 10vw;
  max-width: 33vw;
  color: #fff;
}

.clip {
  height: inherit;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

/* Just some general styles... */
*{margin:0;box-sizing:border-box;}
html,body{height:100%;font:14px/1.4 sans-serif;}
h1{font-weight: 100;font-size:9vh} p{font-size: 2.8vh;}

[class^='bg-'],[class*=' bg-'] {background: fixed center/cover none no-repeat;}
.bg-1{background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1VOY.jpg');}
.bg-2{background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6u3t.jpg');}
.bg-3{background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3ZBA.jpg');}
```

```html
<section class="bg-1">
  <div class="clip">
    <div class="fix">
      <h1>staircase to</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique corporis saepe doloribus optio nulla laudantium accusantium esse nostrum soluta!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="bg-2">
  <div class="clip">
    <div class="fix">
      <h1>the subterrain of</h1>
      <p>Eveniet quaerat architecto nemo in eum accusamus ipsa! Nisi hic laboriosam nesciunt, magnam tempore, praesentium, eveniet iusto est inventore doloremque animi iure</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="bg-3">
  <div class="clip">
    <div class="fix">
      <h1>our great city</h1>
      <p>Optio nulla laudantium accusantium esse nostrum soluta! Consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique corporis saepe doloribus optio nulla</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

---

## *Fixed-alike* and sticky

For a combination of ***visually fixed and sticky***, simply set the content height to `0`. Such will allow the next section to fully overlay the previous content:

```css
section { 
  height: 100vh;
}

.fix {
  position: sticky;
  height: 0; /* this is important to get the top-stop effect */
  top: 20vh;
  left: 10vw;
  max-width: 33vw;
  color: #fff;
}

.clip {
  height: inherit;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

/* Just some general styles... */
*{margin:0;box-sizing:border-box;}
html,body{height:100%;font:14px/1.4 sans-serif;}
h1{font-weight: 100;font-size:9vh} p{font-size: 2.8vh;}

[class^='bg-'],[class*=' bg-'] {background: fixed center/cover none no-repeat;}
.bg-1{background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1VOY.jpg');}
.bg-2{background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6u3t.jpg');}
.bg-3{background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3ZBA.jpg');}
```

```html
<section class="bg-1">
  <div class="clip">
    <div class="fix">
      <h1>staircase to</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique corporis saepe doloribus optio nulla laudantium accusantium esse nostrum soluta!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="bg-2">
  <div class="clip">
    <div class="fix">
      <h1>the subterrain of</h1>
      <p>Eveniet quaerat architecto nemo in eum accusamus ipsa! Nisi hic laboriosam nesciunt, magnam tempore, praesentium, eveniet iusto est inventore doloremque animi iure</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="bg-3">
  <div class="clip">
    <div class="fix">
      <h1>our great city</h1>
      <p>Optio nulla laudantium accusantium esse nostrum soluta! Consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique corporis saepe doloribus optio nulla</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**Tip:**

Since the above uses `height:0` to achieve the full-overlap, but if you really need a content with some height (to apply overflow scroll on smaller screens etc..), in such case create an additional child element with height expressed in `vh` and `overflow: hidden; overflow-y: auto;` if needed.

---

If you need to use `clip-path: url(#fullClip);` place this `svg` in your document

```
<svg width="0" height="0" style="display:block;">
    <defs>
      <clipPath id="fullClip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
        <path d="M0,0 1,0 1,1 0,1"/>
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: This is very close, the only aspect that should differ is that the content shouldn't move like in my example, but be fixed to the section as it's coming into view.

https://i.gyazo.com/dfb1708969cbefcdda93d7a9a9762928.mp4

Almsot like it's a totally separate div that starts to move up the page as you hit the bottom of the section in view.

Comment: @CharlieCoplestone you mean like this? http://output.jsbin.com/qulegecohu/

Comment: Even closer, I've managed to manipulate it in the inspector to do what I want:

https://i.gyazo.com/c79678aee9f586eac4911613cc5ce03d.mp4

Comment: @CharlieCoplestone added a third example.

Comment: The third example is pretty much perfect. Doesn't really work in IE due to `position: sticky` not being supported. I'll have to create the fallback for it. Thanks a lot for your help here, really insightful.